# Emulate RaspberryPi using QEMU

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, qemu, raspbian

I would like to run a RaspberryPi system on my MacOSX using QEMU. I tried the following, using [this tutorial](https://github.com/psema4/pine/wiki/Installing-QEMU-on-OS-X):

> ./qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -hda ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img -kernel kernel.img -append "root=/dev/sda" -serial stdio

Where `ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img` is my RPi image and `kernel.img` precisely comes from `ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img` (I made a copy of it, I am not sure it was a brilliant idea though).

I get two QEMU windows as a result. One has a "Machine" and a "View" menu, and a black screen showing the following message:

> Guest has not initialized the display (yet).

The second one is simply a black window.

I had the same problem using a Raspbian image and the same command. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- First of all, I had to use another kernel, `kernel-qemu` that I found [here](http://xecdesign.com/downloads/linux-qemu/kernel-qemu).
- Then, I could make it work **using QEMU 1.7.1**:

  With Raspbian:

  > ./qemu-system-arm -kernel /path/to/kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda /path/to/2013-12-20-wheezy-raspbian.img

  With Arch Linux, I had to:

  1. Start in terminal mode (not sure if necessary, though) using:

     > ./qemu-system-arm -kernel /path/to/kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "**root=/dev/sda5** panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw **init=/bin/bash**" -hda /path/to/ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img

     *(Note that **init=/bin/bash** was added here, and Arch Linux requires **root=/dev/sda5** instead of sda2)*
  2. Modify `/etc/fstab` as follows (the partition was wrong):

     ```
     # <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
     /dev/sda1       /boot   vfat    defaults        0       0
     ```
  3. Start normally using:

     > ./qemu-system-arm -kernel /path/to/kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda5 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda /path/to/ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img
- I finally realised that I could use the latest version of **QEMU (2.1.1)**, but I had to specify the console output:

  > ./qemu-system-arm -kernel path/to/kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "**console=ttyAMA0** root=/dev/sda5 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda /path/to/ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img

  *(Note that I specified the console using **console=ttyAMA0**)*

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the kernel linked here -- I have the same issue and the page is gone :(

Comment: The one I used in my answer is [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!ZphGyAhI!vunA1J_wskcUJd9VDKmrImDOyKWY30lQM4g_TxPeaXA)

Comment: I tried to recreate this with my own ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img, but arch boots into emergency mode. Any chance you have that image still lying around somewhere? Or any other tips to get the system to boot normally? It complains about /dev/sda1 not being the correct boot device