# QEMU can emulate SD card from Linux but not from OSX

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu

### Short version

I am trying to emulate a RaspberryPi directly from the SD card (using the same commands as presented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156816/emulate-raspberrypi-using-qemu/159668#159668) from MacOSX. I am using QEMU.

However, **the partitions on my SD card are not recognized properly**: when I use the *.img file, QEMU detects the partitions. It does not when I use the SD card, though. Since MacOSX cannot mount ext4 natively, I tried to install osxfuse and fuse-ext2. Now I can mount my ext4 filesystem without problems using:

```
$ mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/disk2s5 /mnt/sda5
```

Running QEMU, I try to specify the filesystem with `rootfstype=fuse-ext2`, but QEMU still does not detect the partitions. Actually, whatever I put in this `rootfstype` field, I get the same error:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "sda5" or unknown-block(8,5): error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
0b00         1048575 sr0  driver: sr
1f00           65536 mtdblock0  (driver?)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,5)
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 3.10.26+ #2
```

### More details

Using the following command, I can emulate my Pi image (`*.img`) successfully (both from **Arch Linux** and from **MacOSX**:

> $ qemu-system-arm -kernel path/to/kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/sda5 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda */path/to/ArchLinuxARM-2014.06-rpi.img*

I can emulate my Pi system from the SD card when I run QEMU from **Arch Linux** (as described in [this link](http://wiki.qemu.org/TexiDemo#host_005fdrives)):

> $ qemu-system-arm -kernel /path/to/kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/sda5 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda */dev/sdd*

Where */dev/sdd* is my SD card as recognized by Arch Linux.
Then I try to run the same from **MacOSX**, as follows:

> $ qemu-system-arm -kernel path/to/kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/sda5 rootfstype=**fuse-ext2** rw" -hda */dev/disk2*

*(Notice that I used "fuse-ext2" which is a third-party on MacOSX).*

This time partitions are not detected and I get the error copied above.

Running the `*.img` file instead of the SD card, three partitions are detected: `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda5`.

Comment: Why are you using QEMU? You can directly partition the SD card on RaspPi. I tried doing that on a USB stick then later I found out you can only run it on SD card. Are you doing a Raspberian install?

Comment: I am trying to emulate a Raspberry Pi from an SD card instead of an image file. The SD card works perfectly well when I start it directly from the Pi.

Comment: What did you use in the `...` parts? Maybe instead of flashing it onto the card, you flashed it onto the first partition?

Comment: `if=/path/to/.img of=/dev/disk2`, with `disk2` being the SD card. Then the SD card works on the Pi, but cannot be read from QEMU.

Comment: While using sd card you may need to run qemu with sudo.

Comment: That's right, and I do it otherwise I get a permissions error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that your sd card is not being seen at all, or incorrectly being presented, so this is not a **partition** issue.

Check your QEMU command for the sdcard instance and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same plan as you to use QEMU to emulate system from SD card under OS X.
Also, I encountered the same issue with you and get stuck with same situation.

Until I found this [doc](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#host_005fdrives).
At 3.6.6.3 Mac OS X, no options for hard disks.

> ‘/dev/cdrom’ is an alias to the first CDROM.
>
> Currently there is no specific code to handle removable media, so it is better to use the change or eject monitor commands to change or eject media.

I guess this is why we always failed emulate system from SD card.